# Building an broken arm64 docker image with buildx multiarch

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to get buildx to work so I can easily make multiarch docker images.
At the moment I'm trying this for an nodejs project.

The building itself does not fail, but when I try to run it on my Raspberry Pi (arm64) it does not work. (It gives me: `exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error`).

This is my buildx command `docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64,linux/amd64,linux/arm -t z0pyrus/photon-reddit:latest . --push`

But running the same command with only `--platform linux/arm64` creates an working docker image.

I have verified that my buildx instance has the necessary dependencies with qemu.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
ARG TARGETARCH
FROM ${TARGETARCH}/node as build-env
ENV BUILDX_ARCH="${TARGETOS:-linux}-${TARGETARCH}"

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install && npm audit fix

CMD [ "npm", "run", "build-and-start" ]
EXPOSE 8080 3306
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining a value for `TARGETARCH`? On top of this, if you're using the dockerhub official base image for node, you don't need to provide a specific architecture as docker engine will automatically pull the architecture your local system/image needs during the build process.

The key output you should also be looking at is the `exec format error`. This means that you are trying to run a docker container whose image architecture is different from the one on your local system. Hence, the reason why the code can't compile and run. This means that even though you think you built a multi-arch image, you didn't actually because the application isn't supported.

I know this issue is old but if it's still relevant could you provide the buildx output?